# What is the output destination of ofstream?

Tags: c++, ofstream

In the following C++ function:

```
void save_data(std::ofstream& csv) {
    csv << "a message";
}
```

Something I don't understand: if `save_data` is called, where does it
write to? To a file? How exactly is it used?

Comment: Unless you are using the function argument to open or close a file, it should be `ostream&` not `ofstream&`.

Comment: did you pay enough attention to why that parameter'csv' has been declared as a 'reference to non-const' AND about the operator <<?

Answer (score 3):

An `ofstream` represents a file on the file system:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream  file("Plop.txt");

    save_data(file);
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I think this is probably a bad choice. The method should probably take an `std::ostream&` parameter and allow saving to any stream, irrespective of whether it represents a file, or a memory buffer, or a network socket, or ...

Comment: It is very bad form. However, it's the OP's function.

Comment: ofstream provides a constructor and open() on top of ostream that initializes the underlying filestreambuf. You can still use ostream::rdbuf() to redirect it elsewhere, not only to a file. So, it does not necessarily represent a file.